# Sendmail alias for all mail users in the domain

Tags: sendmail, aliases

Is there a way to make a global alias in Sendmail so it would send email to all users?
I tried to create an alias and included the list of all my users, but when I try to process it by m4, I receive an error that the line is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sendmail [FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20170223123921/http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.21) would be a good start. (and was the first hit one Googling "sendmail all users" ...)

> There is no magic short-cut for this. But it is not hard to set up: create an aliases entry in `/etc/aliases`
>
> `alluser:        :include:/etc/mail/allusers`
>
> Don't forget to run `newaliases`. Then list your users, one per line, in the file `/etc/mail/allusers`. You might be able to do that with
>
> `awk -F: '$3 > 100 { print $1 }' /etc/passwd > /etc/mail/allusers`